# password matching with international keyboards

Tags: character-encoding, internationalization, password-protection

Recently I had a client from Singapore try to log in to our web-app using a password that we gave him over the phone.

The password was short and alpha-numeric; no special characters.  He couldn't log in after several tries, being very careful to input each character correctly.

We then decided to send him the password over email as a test.

He copy and pasted the password, and successfully logs in.

My theory on why this happened is because he was using a different encoding or international keyboard.  Is there some way to prevent this from happening, or some things I can check for as far as encoding goes?

Comment: There is no reason an international keyboard will cause this. More than likely they misunderstood a character/number over the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Tell him to send back the way he typed it, and compare it. if it's alpha-numeric, there's no reason it would be different.
(English characters are the same worldwide)

Comment: I would if this was a friend, but I don't want to ask a potential client to help debug my software.